# What is default timeout values for THTTPRIO

Tags: delphi, soap, timeout

Hi I know that HTTPRIO does this to set timeouts:

```
if FConnectTimeout > 0 then
  Check(not InternetSetOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FConnectTimeout), SizeOf(FConnectTimeout)));
if FSendTimeout > 0 then
  Check(not InternetSetOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FSendTimeout), SizeOf(FSendTimeout)));
if FReceiveTimeout > 0 then
  Check(not InternetSetOption(Request, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FReceiveTimeout), SizeOf(FReceiveTimeout)));
```

But I would like to know what the default values are. I tried to Google it but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Perhaps try `InternetQueryOption` to find out?

Comment: Yeah I did it and got some numbers. Now my question is are those values are default values for just my pc or are they set by Delphi? What I got for values is 60sec, 30sec and 30sec

Comment: I doubt Delphi would change them. MS usually provides registry keys where these sorts of defaults can be changed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are set by WinInet, so if it varies from PC to PC, it's because of the version of WinInet, and therefore the version of Internet Explorer that's installed.  Setting it in one program should not affect others. i.e. changing the values is good for only the session that you're modifying it for.
We have had to increase the timeouts when sending large XML payloads to a system that takes a long time to return a result.  Up to 300 seconds.